# Are Swift functions assigned/passed by value or by reference?

Tags: swift, function, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment, pass-by-value

When a function in Swift is assigned to a variable or returned, as a nested function, from a higher-level function, is it passed by value or by reference? When I write:

```
func foo() -> Bool
{
    return false
}

var funcVar = foo
```

does `funcVar` receive a reference to `foo()`, or is a copy of `foo()` created and stored in memory with the "funcVar" name? Same question for the following code:

```
func otherfoo() -> (Int) -> ()
{
    func bar(num :Int) {}
    return bar
}

var funcVar = otherfoo()
```

The second example in particular puzzles me because, if I call `funcVar(3)` I should not be able to access `bar` in the case functions are assigned/returned by reference, since `bar` is inside another function at the same scope of `funcVar`, but it still works (coming from a C++ background I'm just surprised it compiles).
Could somebody please shed some light on the matter for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

> In the example above, incrementBySeven and incrementByTen are constants, but the closures these constants refer to are still able to increment the runningTotal variables that they have captured. This is because functions and closures are reference types.
>
> Whenever you assign a function or a closure to a constant or a variable, you are actually setting that constant or variable to be a reference to the function or closure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think of looking at the Closures page of the Documentation - I only read the Functions page. Anyway this settles it: apparently the reference completely ignores the original scope in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Functions are reference types in swift. To further illustrate this by code example.

```
func countAdder(_ word: String)-> () -> (){
var count = 0
func currentCount(){
    count += 1
    print(count)
}
return currentCount
}
let countedWord = countAdder("Hello")
let countedWordTwo = countAdder("World")
countedWord() // count is 1
countedWordTwo() // count is  1
//Lets try this

let countedWord = countAdder("Hello")
let countedWordTwo = countedWord
countedWord() // count is  1
countedWordTwo() // now count is 2
```

I hope it is clear enough to explain the concept.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *everything* in Swift is assigned by value, and *everything* in Swift is passed by value if the parameter doesn't have `ref` and you don't use `&` to pass it. (And if the parameter has `ref` and you use `&` to pass it, it is pass by reference.) This is true regardless of type.

It's unclear what you are asking. You might be asking whether functions are value types (like structs) or reference types (like references to objects), which is a different question. The answer is that, because functions in Swift are immutable (there is no mutable "contents" of a function that you can change), it is semantically indistinguishable whether it's a value type or reference type. It makes no difference either way.

> The second example in particular puzzles me because, if I call
>   funcVar(3) I should not be able to access bar in the case functions
>   are assigned/returned by reference, since bar is inside another
>   function at the same scope of funcVar

I don't understand what you are saying. Functions are first-class citizens. So once you have a function value, you can use it, you can pass it, you can return it, just like anything else, and whoever gets this function can use it like any other function. Whether the function value is a value type that is copied or a reference to a reference-counted object makes no difference.